# How to get interval from day of week from timstamp field in a table in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, date, intervals, data-conversion

I can do the follwoing in Postgres

```
select interval '5 day';
```

Which returns

```
5 days
```

Also I can do

```
select (EXTRACT(DOW from i.closed_on)) || ' day' from issues i;
```

that results in

```
5 day
3 day
7 day
```

But I need to be able to convert this result into intervals. So I am trying to find a way to run something like

```
select interval (EXTRACT(DOW from i.closed_on)) || ' day' from issues i;
```

This gives an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you want.

```
postgres=# select ((EXTRACT(DOW from now())) || ' day')::interval;
 interval
----------
 5 days
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I needed.